# how to solve this problem: dyld[79138]: Library not loaded

Tags: xcode, swift5

dyld[90232]: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/Adjust.framework/Adjust
Referenced from: <13996E90-9595-3B2B-8B91-337B3110C118> /Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/136F87DB-6E73-472B-9C70-5DF65F8341B9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/051FF98F-AFA0-4D8A-8A95-9E78CBF3F732/project_name
Reason: tried: '/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project_name-denkgzfmnxlnnkehwvjmmuldmzjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Adjust.framework/Adjust' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Library/Frameworks/Adjust.framework/Adjust' (errno=2), '/Library/Frameworks/Adjust.framework/Adjust' (errno=2) and crash app by SIGABRT.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.